# Javascript JSON.parse(jsonEmTexto) funciona no Linux mas não no Windows. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, json, cross-platform

Olá, pessoal. Eu tenho uma página HTML que usa AngularJS para exibir um `JSON` que é passado usando o `encodeURI()`. No Linux eu consigo passar esse `JSON` sem problemas, mas quando a mesma página função é feita no Windows, dá erro de formatação de `JSON`.

O código abaixo é JavaScript.

Aqui estou enviando o JSON usando o `encodeURI()`.

`var modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'paginas/etiqueta/verEtiqueta.html?ETiqueta=' + encodeURI(objProduto));
                    var win = new BrowserWindow({
                        width: screen.width,
                        height: screen.height
                    });
                    win.on('close', function() {
                        win = null
                    });
                    win.loadURL(modalPath);
                    win.show();`

---

Aqui estou recebendo o JSON pegando o parâmetro pela URL e usando `decodeURIComponent()` para isso.

`var x = location.search.substring(10);
            var xx = decodeURIComponent(x);
            var objetoOriginal = JSON.parse(xx);`

No linux a variável `objetoOriginal` recebe valor da variável `xx` e retorna um objeto normal, já no Windows a variável `objetoOriginal` não recebe valor e o console retorna erro de formatação de `JSON`.
Para não deixar a pergunta muito extensa, deixo o "JSON" que a variável `xx` recebe apos o `decodeURIComponent(x)` retornar o valor, resultado que a variálvel `xx`  nesse link http://pastebin.com/JwnAEqC5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom para quem tiver com esse problema a solução é usar a função `eval` do javaScript, bom basicamente como o `JSON` que estou passando e muito longo em alguns casos o `JSON.parse()` pode não funcionar

`// X recebe o JSON da URL cortando fora o inicio que serio o parametro '?Rparametro=' deixando apenas o encodo do JSON`

`var x = location.search.substring(10);
var objetoOriginal = eval('(' + decodeURIComponent(x) + ')');`

no console se usarmos o comando `typeof`

`typeof objetoOriginal`
retorna o tipo da variável como sendo objeto.